# Why does this code use <function>.call()?

Tags: javascript

Code is from [mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0)
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product "' + name + '" with a negative price');
  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
   Product.call(this, name, price);/// why not this be Product(name,price)
   this.category = 'food';
}
Food.prototype = new Product();
```

may very silly thing,  can't understand this line
 `Product.call(this, name, price);`

Since both Product and Food are global functions why do we have to use Product.call

Comment: [What is the reason *not* to use the `new` keyword for inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to apply the `Product` function on the food object. Just invoking it without [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) would lead to a wrong [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), and the properties added in `Product` would be attached to the wrong object.

Also learn [here about inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572).

Answer (score 3):

The `Product` function is a constructor, this would normally be called with `new`.  Using `new` when calling a function creates a new empty object, and calls the function with the new object as the context, it also sets up the prototype chain.

In this example `Food` is sub-classing `Product`, it wants to run the Product constructor on the new instance of `Food`.

An example should make things clear:

```
var f = new Food ('apple', 10)

f.name = 'apple'
f.price = 10
f.category = 'food'
```

The name and price category is being added to the object by calling the `Product` constructor with the new instance of `Food`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Product.call(this, name, price);
```

This line calls the product function with `this` as the calling object and name and price as arguments

This allows you to treat product as a method of Food without explicitly assigning it.   Without doing this, any calls to "this" within product would point to the global object.  Instead they are now assigned to the instance of Food that is being created.

A possible purpose of doing this in this case is to use Product to prepare the object in the constructor without making product a permanent part of the Food objects definition (which would happen if you assigned it as a method of Food, while still allowing it to be reused by others (which would be impossible if you made it part of the logic of the constructor function or an internal function within the constructor)

Answer (score 1):

in this case

```
Product.call(this, name, price);
```

this -> is Food instance, not window

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of invoking functions in JavaScript.

One of them is by calling the `call` method of the function object. It accepts the context (the meaning of `this` inside the function) and the function's arguments as other arguments.

*Example:*

```
var context = { foo: 'bar' };
function func(a, b, c) {
   console.log(this.foo);
   console.log(a, b, c);
}
func.call(context, 1, 2, 3);
//'bar'
//1 2 3
```

There's one more method which is similar to `call` it's `apply`. It accepts two arguments - the context and array with the parameters of the function.

Answer (score 1):

the `call` function is a method of all `Function` objects. It allows you to pass a specific context to a function, essentially setting what the `this` keyword will be inside the function.

[MDN Documentation for call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)